# update ruby to 1.8.7

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a project that i have to use ruby 1.8.7. I'm using today, ruby 1.8.6 + Mac OSX Darwin. This ruby 1.8.6 was installed with the OS, it's a developer package from Apple. My question is: how can i update this package? if i run ports, it dont find my current installed package and install a new ruby version, with different paths and as effect it breaks my rubygems (i know how to fix it, but it is always workarounds over workarounds).

There is a clean way to update the default ruby that comes with the OS or its better to remove it and just manage it by Port? Please answer like this one [How to update to Ruby 1.8.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891120/how-to-update-to-ruby-1-8-7) don't helps me

Comment: people voting down in 2017 a question from 2009? Back in the days rvm was pretty new and no homebrew.. tsc tsc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `rvm` gem? It manages Ruby versions installed, allow to compile most (if not all) actual (and archival) Ruby versions, sets proper environment variables pointing to actually used ruby version.

```
$ gem install rvm
$ rvm install 1.8.7
$ rvm use 1.8.7 --default
```

Answer (score 0):

On my OS X machines I have several versions of Ruby installed.

I install then, from source, under /usr/local/ruby-1.X.X

Once you have multiple versions of Ruby installed you will need your environment to know which one to use.

I do this by setting the PATH, like so

`export PATH="/usr/local/ruby-1.8.7/bin:$PATH";`

See [Hive Logic's article on installing Ruby](http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-leopard)